# how to display session values without reloading page

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

i am trying to display my servlet session output to my webpage using jsp pages. 
 below is my code for javascript and jsp. For reference i have attached the small 
 portion from servlet also.
 The values are coming but only when i refresh the webpage, that is why i used 
"location.reload()", but when i remove it, the values does not come.
 i need it without  refreshing as soon i click the button. 
Plz tell me how can i display this values for active and nonactive session on the 
 webpage without reloading. Thanks in advance!

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#preview2').click(function(event) {

         var cno = $('#cardnumber').val();
         $.post('DigitRef', {
             cardnumber : cno
         });
//              location.reload();
 });



 $('#service1').click(function(event) {



     var btn = $('#service1').attr("name");
     $.post('Leis1', {
         servno:btn

     });
//          location.reload();

});


 $('#service3').click(function(event) {



     var btn = $('#service3').attr("name");
     $.post('Leis1', {
         servno:btn
     });
//          location.reload();

});

$('#service2').click(function(event) {



 var btn = $('#service2').attr("name");
 $.post('Leis1', {
     servno:btn
  });
//      location.reload();

});


});
```

jsp

```
<div class="success" id="serv7">
    <c:if test="${not empty active}">
        <c:out value="${active}"/>
    </c:if>
        <% session.setAttribute("active", ""); %>
</div>
    <div id="serv8" class="error">
        <c:if test="${not empty notactive}">
            <c:out value="${notactive}"/>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty Unbe}">
          <c:out value="${Unbe}"/>
        </c:if>
            <% session.setAttribute("notactive", ""); %>
           <% session.setAttribute("Unbe", "Unbekannte Karte");%>
</div>



servlet:

else if(!(arrival_date_cust.compareTo(new Date())<0&&(newDate().compareTo(lastDayDate_cust)<0))) 
                             {
                                   servNotActive=true;
                                    System.out.println("Karte ausserhalb des Gültigkeitszeitraums.");

                                    session.setAttribute("notactive", "Karte ausserhalb des Gültigkeitszeitraums.");
                            }




                             // Program for Limitation MindestAufenthalt (Minimum Stay of Guest)  Instant cards

                            else if(allgs.getLef_MindestAufenthalt()>Integer.parseInt(gac_Aufenthaltsdauer))
                            {
                                //cannot use
                                servNotActive=true;
                                System.out.println("Leistung durch zu geringen MindestAufhenthalt nicht verfügbar. Sie müssen mindestens " + allgs.getLef_MindestAufenthalt()+" Tage Aufenthalten.");

                                session.setAttribute("notactive", "Leistung durch zu geringen MindestAufhenthalt nicht verfügbar.");

                            }
```

Comment: please properly edit and format your question

Comment: Thanks @Jai. Sorry  i am very new to stackoverflow, so could not properly formated.